# Proyecto con diferentes modulos Maven

Tags: java, maven

me pidieron que hiciera un ejemplo de como seria trabajar con diferentes módulos usando maven, pero he tenido problemas a la hora de hacer una prueba, porque al agregar la dependencia x a un módulo y, y luego querer usar una clase del módulo x, no me lo permite si no es importando toda la clase

En el pom del módulo y tengo la dependencia así

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.bmsoft.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myApp-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

La clase del modulo x:

```
package org.myApp.api;

public class Constantes {
    public static String nombre_app="Proyecto Modulos";
}
```

La clase del modulo Y:

```
package org.MyApp.ejb;


public class CompraApp {
    String a = Constantes.nombre_app;
}
```

Y ahi es donde sale mi error, ejecutan lo de maven install pude observar esto, no se si aporte:

```
Failed to execute goal on project MyApp-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.bmsoft.myapp:MyApp-ejb:ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.bmsoft.myapp:myApp-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *importando la clase*? ¿Copiarla en tu proyecto principal? Tiene pinta de que en tu pom.xml  no estás declarando los proyectos hijos correctamente. Quizá deberías añadir el POM completo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás experimentando se debe a un problema de resolución de dependencias en tu proyecto Maven. Parece que estás intentando utilizar una clase del módulo x en el módulo y, pero Maven no puede encontrar la dependencia myApp-api en el repositorio local o remoto. Para resolver este problema, sigue estos pasos:

Asegúrate de que el módulo x (myApp-api) se ha compilado y empacado correctamente en un archivo JAR. Debes construirlo antes de intentar utilizarlo en el módulo y.

Verifica que tengas configurado el proyecto x correctamente en su archivo POM (pom.xml) para que genere un JAR en su fase de construcción. Debería tener una configuración similar a esta:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version> <!-- Versión actualizada del plugin -->
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass> <!-- Si tienes una clase principal -->
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Asegúrate de que el módulo x se haya instalado en tu repositorio local Maven correctamente. Para hacerlo, desde la carpeta raíz de x, ejecuta el siguiente comando Maven:

```
mvn install
```

Esto instalará el artefacto myApp-api en tu repositorio local.

Luego, asegúrate de que la dependencia se esté resolviendo correctamente en el módulo y. Comprueba que el pom.xml del módulo y tenga la dependencia correctamente definida como lo mencionaste:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.bmsoft.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myApp-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

Vuelve a compilar el módulo y después de asegurarte de que el módulo x se haya instalado correctamente. Desde la carpeta raíz de y, ejecuta:

```
mvn compile
```

Esto debería resolver el problema de resolución de dependencias y permitirte utilizar la clase Constantes del módulo x en el módulo y. Asegúrate de que ambos módulos tengan una estructura de proyecto Maven válida y de que los nombres de los paquetes y artefactos se correspondan con los valores definidos en los archivos POM.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Iván Vázquez